# Divs not in a straight line when centering them

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center 4 div boxes in a straight vertical line using translate method you use when centering objects in the middle of the screen, [this](https://codepen.io/poptudor/pen/VVwoQP) is the code I used:

```css
.body-component {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #ff6d00;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #D0D3D4;
}

.width-medium {
  width: 500px;
}

.height-medium {
  height: 400px;
}

.code-snippet {
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.snippet-title {
  position: absolute;
  color: #248b98;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  z-index: 1;
}

.center {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0px;
}

.boxes {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #056ab3;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-20%, -50%);
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #056ab3;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-40%, -50%);
}

.box3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #056ab3;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-60%, -50%);
}

.box4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #056ab3;
  top: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-80%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="body-component width-medium height-medium">
      <span class="snippet-title">Box loading animation</span>
      <div class="code-snippet center">
        <div class="boxes">
          <div class="box1"></div>
          <div class="box2"></div>
          <div class="box3"></div>
          <div class="box4"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried multiple methods to fix this, but I would not like to centre them using pixels because I am using this on a responsive website.

Comment: you are using different value for each one so they will not get centred ... why not simply using `50%` everywhere?

Comment: @Termani because I want to make an animation out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... add `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to box classes

```css
.body-component {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #ff6d00;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #D0D3D4;
}

.width-medium {
  width: 500px;
}

.height-medium {
  height: 400px;
}

.code-snippet {
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.snippet-title {
  position: absolute;
  color: #248b98;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  z-index: 1;
}

.center {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0px;
}

.boxes {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #056ab3;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #056ab3;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #056ab3;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #056ab3;
  top: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="body-component width-medium height-medium">
      <span class="snippet-title">Box loading animation</span>
      <div class="code-snippet center">
        <div class="boxes">
          <div class="box1"></div>
          <div class="box2"></div>
          <div class="box3"></div>
          <div class="box4"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If absolute positioning, you can use `left: 50%` with a negative `translateX` of 50%.

```css
.body-component {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #ff6d00;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #D0D3D4;
}

.width-medium {
  width: 500px;
}

.height-medium {
  height: 400px;
}

.code-snippet {
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.snippet-title {
  position: absolute;
  color: #248b98;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  z-index: 1;
}

.center {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0px;
}

.boxes {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #056ab3;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.box1 {
  top: 20%;
}

.box2 {
  top: 40%;
}

.box3 {
  top: 60%;
}

.box4 {
  top: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-component width-medium height-medium">
  <span class="snippet-title">Box loading animation</span>
  <div class="code-snippet center">
    <div class="boxes">
      <div class="box box1"></div>
      <div class="box box2"></div>
      <div class="box box3"></div>
      <div class="box box4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That said, you could use flexbox to achieve this layout without having to *know* the number of the boxes in advance for the purpose of vertical spacing.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #248b98;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.body-component {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 10px solid #ff6d00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-betwen;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.snippet-title {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding: 10px;
}

.code-snippet {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.boxes {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.box {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #056ab3;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-component">
  <span class="snippet-title">Box loading animation</span>
  <div class="code-snippet">
    <div class="boxes">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```